# VM volume showing up in /Volumes

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

I notice that if i run a first-aid scan in the Disk Utility app on what's known as "Container disk1", it shows a mounted volume called "VM". To my understanding, VM stands for "VirtualMemory" and its a volume that is mounted but hidden in the Finder; it shows up in the Disk Utility app as an amount of storage of 'Container disk1' and doesnt show itself mounted(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPkk1.png). But ive seem to notice every time after a first-aid scan is finished preforming on 'Container disk1' it shows VM mounted in the Finder; restarting my MacBook makes VM hidden again. Here are the steps i used to produce this:

1) restart MacBook into normal boot mode(even if already on)

2) after restart open the Disk Utility app and select 'Show All Devices' in View

3) select 'Container disk1' and run a first-aid scan on the container disk

4) open "/Volumes" path in the Finder after first-aid is finished

Im unsure if this is expected behavior of the first-aid scan on the 'Container disk1' and im unable to test it out on another MacBook as i only have the one. Is this expected/normal behavior? Can anyone else test this out for me to see if VM also shows itself mounted after running first-aid on 'Container disk1'?

Comment: Did you ever use Disk Utility debug menu as show [here](https://www.macstories.net/stories/miscellaneous-lion-tips-and-tricks-part-2/) to show other partitions?

Comment: @Trellis from my understanding, Disk Utility doesnt have the debug menu anymore, especially in High Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is normal behavior of the new APFS format as scanning the container disk will show the VM volume in the finder as it's scanned